# Why is sprintf giving asterisks instead of my formatted string?

Tags: php, printf

This code:

```
    function atest(){
    $test = array(
        "StartDate" => "08/01/2013", 
        "StartTime" =>"08:00:00", 
        "DepartmentID" => "75275", 
        "# Contacts Offered" => "3", 
        "# Contacts Handled" => "4", 
        "Average Talk Time" => "491.250000", 
        "Average Delay" => "5.666667", 
        "Percent SLA" => "1.333333");

    $formatted = sprintf("%s   %s TCSDATA %d %d %d %01.2f 0 %01.2f %01.2f 0\r\n", 
        $test["StartDate"],
        $test["StartTime"],
        $test['DepartmentID'],
        $test['# Contacts Offered'],
        $test['# Contacts Handled'],
        $test['Average Talk Time'],
        $test['Average Delay'],
        $test['Percent SLA']
    );

    echo('<pre>');
    echo( var_dump($test) );
    echo('</pre>');             

    echo $formatted;
}
```

Prints this:

```
08/01/2013 08:00:00 TCSDATA 75275 ************************
```

However, if I modify the sprintf format to remove the last 0 as such:

```
"%s   %s TCSDATA %d %d %d %01.2f 0 %01.2f %01.2f \r\n"
```

I get this:

```
08/01/2013 08:00:00 TCSDATA 75275 3 4 491.25 0 5.67 1.33
```

What in the world?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using (down to the patch version, if you could)?

Comment: 5.3.2, not sure how to get the patch version

Comment: `PHPINFO();` will display down to the patch

Comment: I tried to re-produce here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ after @Kolink (in his awesomeness) said he couldn't reproduce.  Looks like an issue in the environment.

Patch is php-5.3.2-1302

Comment: Does anything change if you use single quotes for your format string (while keeping the zero)?

Comment: @JustinY17 Search the PHP bugs for something related to `sprintf` with this particular set of characters (0\r\n). I'd recommend an upgrade to 5.4

Comment: @JustinY17 Maybe the `#` symbols are causing this or the numbers shouldn't be inside double-quotes? From what I could tell in the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: Could not reproduce in several versions [1](http://3v4l.org/iCro8) [2](http://3v4l.org/WGTOZ).

Comment: @Fred, I attempted with single quotes, same issue.  I am running this code in a hosted environment (oracle) and have submitted a ticket to them.

Comment: @JustinY17 Like you say, it's very bizarre. Now, from the experience I have in a totally different area, am under the impression that the `\r\n` need to be concatenated; why, I don't know. Have you tried this `$formatted = sprintf("%s   %s TCSDATA %d %d %d %01.2f 0 %01.2f %01.2f 0"."\r\n",`

Comment: You could also try replacing the `0` with `%d` and a zero as input, or a `%s` with the "\r\n" as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was actually caused because the sequence of numbers matched the Luhn Algorithm, and was being masked in my PCI environment.  I manually excluded the file from the test, and everything now is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Even PHP 5.3.20 (cli) (built: Dec 20 2012 06:20:32) cannot reproduce this bug, so upgrading to 5.4 may be not required.